# Brownian and Brackets

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingales, stochastic-analysis

> A continuous martingale with deterministic bracket must be a Brownian motion.

Is this statement ture or not, please? If true, how to show it? If not, what is a counter example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A continuous martingale is a Brownian motion if and only if its quadratic
variation over each interval $[0, t]$ is equal to $t$.

Thus, if $M$ is a continuous martingale and $\langle M\rangle_t=u(t)$ for some deterministic function $u$, then $M$ is a *time change* of a Brownian motion in the sense that $M_t=B_{u(t)}$ for every $t$, where $B$ is a Brownian motion.

Note that each martingale as above such that $u$ is $C^1$ can be realized as $$M_t=M_0+\int_0^t\sqrt{u'(s)}\,\mathrm d\beta_s,$$ for some (other) Brownian motion $\beta$.

To sum up, if you ask that $M$ is exactly a Brownian motion, $M=2B$ disproves the claim, but if you ask only that $M$ is a Brownian motion with a change of time, there is no counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** consider the martingales
$$
M(t) = \int 1_{[0,t]}(s) a(s) dB(s)
$$with $a\in L^2(R^+)$. Then $$
\langle M\rangle(t) = \int 1_{[0,t]}(s) a(s)^2 ds
$$

Comment: I guess for your example, it is necessary to disprove that $M(t)$ is a Brownian motion since the bracket is clearly deterministic. Then we have a counter example. Right?

Comment: right!${{{}}}{}$

Comment: I tried to disprove your example. I tested against the normality condition, i.e., $M(t_1) - M(t_2)$ should be normal with mean $0$ and variance $t_1 - t_2$ if $t_1 > t_2$. I found that this will only work when $a(s)=1$, which is not guaranteed. Is this right, please? Thank you!

Comment: there are continuous martingales that do not satisfy $M(t_1) - M(t_2)$ has variance $|t_2 - t_1|$.

Comment: Yes, that is what I tried to say. We need extra condition on $a$ to make it work. Right?

Comment: no, an $L^2$ function guarantees a martingale.